# What is the correct term to describe the moment after cessation of code execution?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setimmediate

In JavaScript one can cause code to be executed immediately after the current bit of code has finished executing a la setImmediate or setTimeout(..., 0).

What is the correct term for referring to the gap in execution?

I want to know because I am writing a utility for unit testing that allows a test to continue once one of these gaps has occurred and I want to give it a meaningful name.

At present my code looks like this and the function is just called wait:

```
export default function wait(done, ...callbacks) {
  let callbackIndex = 0;
  function invokeNext() {
    if (typeof callbacks[callbackIndex] === 'function') {
      setImmediate(() => {
        try {
          callbacks[callbackIndex]();
        }
        catch (e) {
          return done(e);
        }
        callbackIndex += 1;
        invokeNext();
      });
    } else {
      return done();
    }
  }
  invokeNext();
}
```

It is used like this:

```
wait(done, () => {
  //... assert something after first code gap
}, 
() => {
  //... assert something after second code gap
});
```

Comment: To take an operating system analogy, I would say that you _yield_ control to the kernel (here: the browser). But because **yield** is now a Javascript keyword, it's probably not such a good idea...

Comment: can you try conjunction  with setTimeout i.e ( setTimeout (500, callbacks[callbackIndex]());

Answer (score 0):

You could describe the "gap" as a "task queue check", "task check" or "queue check", see [Efficient Script Yielding](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/setImmediate/Overview.html#processingmodel)

> 7. [Queue](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) the *task* [task](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#concept-task).